# How do I integrate google cloud endpoints for python with an existing GAE project?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

When I try to integrate google cloud endpoints into an existing project I get this error:

```
 ImportError: No module named endpoints
```

I've already added endpoints to my app.yaml file. The endpoints api file that works externally with its own app.yaml file, but gives the error when run from within the project directory. I'm routing all api calls to "endpoints_api.py" for simplicity. Maybe I'm missing something.

This is my directory setup:

```
    -project
      -handlers
      -media
      -templates
      -webapp2_extras
      __init__.py
      app.yaml
      main.py
      endpoints_api.py
```

Here is my app.yaml file:

```
    application: project-aplha
    version: 1
    runtime: python27
    api_version: 1
    threadsafe: true

    handlers:
    # Endpoints Api
    - url: /_ah/spi/.*
      script: endpoints_api.APPLICATION

    - url: /favicon\.ico
      static_files: media/favicon.ico
      upload: media/favicon.ico

    - url: /media
      static_dir: media

    # Main Script
    - url: /.*
      script: main.APPLICATION

    libraries:
    - name: endpoints
      version: 1.0

    - name: webapp2
      version: latest

    - name: jinja2
      version: latest

    - name: pycrypto
      version: latest
```

And a sample of a handler class (if that matters):

```
class SignupHandler(base.BaseHandler):
 def get(self):
    return self.render_template('sighup.html')

 def post(self):
    name = self.request.get('name')
    email = self.request.get('email')
    password = self.request.get('password')
```

Perhaps the endpoints_api.py file too:

```
import endpoints
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import remote


class Task(messages.Message):
  name = messages.StringField(1, required=True)
  owner = messages.StringField(2)

class TaskModel(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  owner = ndb.StringProperty()

@endpoints.api(name='tasks', version='v1',
               description='API for Task Management')
class TaskApi(remote.Service):

  @endpoints.method(Task, Task,
                    name='task.insert',
                    path='task',
                    http_method='POST')
  def insert_task(self, request):
    TaskModel(name=request.name, owner=request.owner).put()
    return request

APPLICATION = endpoints.api_server([TaskApi])
```

Comment: You haven't really supplied any where near enough information for people to do anything more than guess. For instance have you enabled endpoints in your app.yaml , what do your handlers in app.yaml look like etc....

Comment: The context above states that endpoints was added to the app.yaml file. I'm routing all "/_ah/api/explorer" links to use endpoints_api.py rather than main.py. Adding app.yaml and sample of handler above

Comment: why your APPLICATION is upper-cased?

Comment: how do you run your project locally?

Comment: Changed application to APPLICATION. Also Changed the wording to make things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error with the latest AppEngine SDK 1.9.40 on OS X. The `endpoints` module is not in the Python module search path and thus when your code runs `import endpoints`, it fails with an ImportError.

Even running with the GUI GoogleAppEngineLauncher, the module is unreferenced.

On OS X, the module is at `/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/endpoints-1.0/endpoints`. You can verify this by adding it to your PYTHONPATH and then from the interpreter run `import endpoints`. This should work although it will fail as it has an internal reference to `protorpc'.

Unfortunately on the command-line, the `dev_appserver.py` fails to reference PYTHONPATH and thus you continue to get an ImportError with a command like:

`dev_appserver.py  --datastore_path=datastore.db .`

And for the record, I am including it in my `app.yaml`:

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
- name: endpoints
  version: "1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must run your project with latest version of Google Cloud SDK.

Switch to your project folder and run it by the following command:

`dev_appserver.py .`

Comment: The endpoints api works with its own app.yaml file but wont run when I integrate with an existing project. Will update the app engine sdk and report back.